# Do not allow any owner to revoke ownership of the user who created the room/MUC - Ejabberd XMPP

Tags: android, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I am developing a messaging app for Android using ejabberd XMPP. App has a room chat feature (MUC).
I have a question regarding MUC owner affiliation.

userA(Creator) creates a new room (MUC).
UserB joins the room and userA(Creator) grants ownership to userB.
userB revokes ownership of userA(Creator) 
userA(Creator) is now none (this is the problem)

I want to know how to configure XMPP server to not allow any owner to revoke ownership of the user who created the room/MUC ?

https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html

Comment: You may find some workarounds for your own custom use cases. But in the long run, you would end up in writing up a custom module on the server and you have to deviate from standard XMPP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement a custom ejabberd module and use [muc_process_iq](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/20.07/src/mod_muc_room.erl#L416) hook.
When someone tries to revoke ownership it sends an IQ stanza to MUC, You can catch it by above hook.
Your hook's callback function should be something like:

```erlang
my_callback(IQ, MUCState) ->
    % check if it's for granting/revoking ownership
    % ...
    NewIQ. % or atom 'ignore'
```

But you do not have creator jid in `MUCState` because in XMPP it does not matter!
Actually there is a hack. Each affiliation can be set with a custom reason which is just a text inside `<reason>...</reason>` tag. You can access owners' affiliation reasons in `MUCState`.
Room creator (first owner) does not have reason in it's affiliation. So when someone is granting ownership, you can put something into 'reason' field (you need to do it in user scope, e.g. `user_send_packet` hook) and let MUC handle it and when someone is revoking ownership check if target owner has 'reason' filed or not in above function.
Also there is more advanced and standard approach to do it. You can change [MUC config state](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/20.07/include/mod_muc_room.hrl#L35) and add creator jid and some changes in `mod_muc_room.erl`. So you can have creator's jid in `MUCState` in above function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am new to Erlang. for me its hard to make any change in module files. can you provide me more details or some code snippets ?.

Comment: I see. Actually there is no specific documentation for this. The only way is to read source code and write/modify modules on top ot it.